# Differentiate $\log_3(7x+2)$

Tags: derivatives

> Differentiate $\log_3(7x+2)$

I used the chain rule for this equation, making $u=7x+2$ and $g=\log_3u$. I then calculated $u'$ to be $7$ and $g'$ to be $\frac{1}{(7x+2)\cdot \ln3}$. Now all thats left is to multiply $u'$ and $g'$.
$$f'(x)=\frac{7}{(7x+2)\cdot \ln3}$$

In my book it says that this is not correct. Any ideas or hints?

Comment: You should always use just enough parentheses to make sure that groupings are clear, and never too few so as to let it be unclear.  $\log_37x+2$ is unclear whether you mean $\log_3(7x)+2$, $\log_3(7x+2)$, $(\log_3(7))x+2$ or something else entirely.  Without looking at your attempt and seeing your choice of $u$, I would have initially assumed it was the first.

Comment: Indeed, $\log_3 7x+2$ means (unambiguously) $(\log_3(7x)) + 2$. I have edited the post accordingly.

Comment: @JMoravitz or you could have looked at the mathjax code :)

Comment: "*In my book it says that this is not correct...*"  There are sometimes many different ways you can write the same thing.  What does your book say the answer is?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire it should be up to the original poster to check to make sure that the MathJax was parsed correctly and outputted the correct intended equation (*preferably before pressing the post/submit button*), it shouldn't ever be the situation that in order to read a question correctly we need to look at the MathJax code instead of what MathJax actually produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

We have $$\log_3(7x+2)=\frac{\ln(7x+2)}{\ln3}$$ and by the Chain Rule, $$\frac d{dx}\ln(7x+2)=\frac1{7x+2}\cdot7$$ so you get that the derivative is $$\frac7{(7x+2)\ln3}$$